# SphereOJ Prime Generator submission error

Tags: python-3.x, input, integer, primes, submission

I know there are some answers on website on this issue, but trust me none of them are helping. Some have not working code claiming to be working.

I keep getting this error at runtime, NZEC, maybe because of spaces and all or type of input it takes but I have tried everything. Please help me, it been 5 hrs + already on this problem. I am sharing my basic code, please visit the problem if necessary and suggest me something.

```
import sys
def isprime(n):
    if n==1:
        return False
    if n==2:
       return True
    l=n//2
    for i in range(2,l+1):
        if(n%i==0):
            return False
    return True
t=int(input())
if t<=10:
    for q in range(t):
         m=int(input("Lower Number"))
         n=int(input("Higher number"))
         if (m>=1 and m<=1000000000 and n>m and n<=1000000000 and n-m<=100000):
             for i in range(m,n+1):
                if isprime(i):
                    print(i)
else:
    quit()
```

I went and checked submitted answer on codechef, and they were accepting answers which don't even give correct output on my local machine. I don't understand this submission thing, help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'd run the code in your local environment to get a real error. Generic errors returned by challenge sites generally aren't that useful.

Comment: It is running perfectly in local environment. problem is type of input at SPhereOJ.

Comment: NZEC is a non-zero exit code.  You need to test all paths through your code and check the exit code for all of them.